# XSLT not displaying at all

Tags: xml, xslt

I am an absolute beginner in using xml and xslt.

I have an xml document and an xslt document but for some reason, i can't get it to display correctly in the browser (internet explorer).

Any insight into why this is occurring would be appreciated. Does it have to do with the namespaces? I have a namespace but the examples i've seen do not actually include namespaces in their xml documents. That is the only thing that i can think of that would be causing me problems.

Thanks.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="D:\menu.xsl" ?>
<menu xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://www.wasabi.com/pakistan/menu"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.wasabi.com/pakistan/menu file:///D:/XML/schemas/menuSchema.xsd" > <!--Tells the document where to find the associated schema-->

<menuItem>
    <name>chicken</name>
    <price>$9.99</price>
    <image> 
        <img src="chiccken.png"/>
    </image>
    <description>
    <!--Just some flavor text -->
       <![CDATA[ 
                 hello there blah. 
                ]]>
    </description>
    <calories>
        <calorieCount> 1200 </calorieCount> <!--set as integer -->
    </calories>
    <icon/>
</menuItem>

<menuItem>
    <name>turkey</name>
    <price>$4.99</price>
    <image> 
        <img src="turkey.png"/>
    </image>
    <description>
       <![CDATA[ 
                 lorem ipsum ...
                ]]>
    </description>
    <calories>
        <calorieCount> 500 </calorieCount>
    </calories>
    <icon iconName="Sodium">&#9830;</icon><!--Character reference that tells customer that means the dish is low in sodium -->
</menuItem>
```

Here is my XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                document.title = 
(location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 
1)).replace('.xml','');

            });
            </script>



            <title> </title>


        </head>

        <body>

             <xsl:apply-templates/>  

        </body>

    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="menuItem">
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>  
    <xsl:apply-templates select="price"/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name">
  Name: <span style="color:#ff0000">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
  <br />
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="price">
  Price: <span style="color:#ff0000">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
  <br />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, your xml-stylesheet processing instruction

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="D:\menu.xsl" ?>
```

is wrong. Firstly, the href value is supposed to be a URI, not a Windows filename. Secondly, many browsers, depending on the security settings selected, won't read a stylesheet from local filestore: they need an HTTP connection.

Comment: It's for school, so it doesn't matter at the moment but that is VERY good to know. I appreciate the insight

Answer (score 0):

If your input XML file uses default namespace, you must declare it in the stylesheet like following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:pm="http://www.wasabi.com/pakistan/menu">
```

Then use namespace prefix "pm" to @match attribute or @select attribute:

```
<xsl:template match="pm:menu">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pm:menuItem">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="pm:name"/>  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="pm:price"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pm:name">
    Name: <span style="color:#ff0000">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
    <br />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pm:price">
    Price: <span style="color:#ff0000">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
    <br />
</xsl:template>
```

The sample result:

[image: Sample result in Chrome]

Please note that your input XML and stylesheet files are not well-formed.

Comment: I actually managed to correct my errors a bit after I posted. Thank you though for taking the time to help me out anyways.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, there were some fatal errors in your xml and stylesheet that prevented them from being processed.  One was the omission of the closing `</menu>` tag in the xml, the other was the unclosed `<xsl:template ... >` element in the stylesheet.  This could have been the reason for the stylesheet not producing any output as you reported.

After correcting these errors, we note that the three templates: `menuItem,` `name,` and `price` are not being called at all.  This is indeed a result of the fact that these elements have the namespace:

```
xmlns="http://www.wasabi.com/pakistan/menu"
```

in the XML input file but no namespace in the xslt file.

So, all the HTML formatting inside these templates was being ignored and the stylesheet was simply outputting unformatted text.  The only reason it was outputting anything at all is because the top-level template `<xsl:template match="/"` matches *any* document element in *any* namespace.  Then the default cascade of xslt was taking over in order to produce the output, which is why the resulting html would look something like this after correcting the well-formedness errors in the input files:

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mjw5O.png)

One way to fix this is by providing a namespace prefix in the xml as suggested above, then you can reference the fully qualified name in the stylesheet.  For example, if you used a namespace prefix of `pm` in your xml, then *all* of your elements in your xml would have to be prefixed with `pm:` and the namespace declaration in the xml would become:

```
xmlns:pm="http://www.wasabi.com/pakistan/menu"
```

Another way is to *remove* the default namespace declaration

```
xmlns="http://www.wasabi.com/pakistan/menu"
```

from the xml.  I tried this on your xml and indeed all the templates are being called and the html looks as expected in a browser window:

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NfH1.png)

Hope this helps you to understand what is going on here ...

J.

Comment: I actually managed to correct my errors a bit after I posted. Thank you though for taking the time to help me out anyways.